# Using Select 2 with form_for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-select2, form-for

I am using select2 for a form in rails, I can not figure out how to get the multiselect to work with form_for, I select2 working but it currently will only accept one input, I need to be able to select multiple selections.

Below is the form

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#list-markets").select2({
     placeholder: "Select your Market"
    });
  });
  </script>
<%= f.select(:type_of_business, Market.get_markets, {}, class: "form-control", id: "list-markets") %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want your select input to accept multiple options, you need to pass in the multiple: true option. I,E:

```
<%= f.select(:type_of_business, Market.get_markets.collect {|m| [ m.name, m.id] }, class: "form-control", id: "list-markets", multiple: true) %>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, I have another question do you know if it is possible to have the name of a Market displayed but pass the id in the parameter. Market.get_markets returns an array of names, how could I also pass the id in this form?

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect your last question. This assumes that Market.get_markets returns and array of Market objects from the database.

Comment: Hey man thanks for all your help, I got it working when I returned all the objects in Market.get_markets it did not work but I had Market.get_markets return an array of arrays with the market name and id it worked.